# How to apply Smooth Shading to dae models rendered with Three.js ColladaLoader

Tags: webgl, three.js

Here is a model which is rendered using the collada loader example in threejs. I believe it is using a Flat Shading. (Thus the blocky nose)

[image]

Now here is the model using a Smooth Shader in meshlab

[image]

I already know how to apply smooth-shading on an obj/js file using MeshFaceMaterial. My question is how can I apply smooth-shading on a dae file which has been rendered using the collada loader? Is this supported in threejs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
callBack = function colladaReady( collada ) {
    var dae = collada.scene;
    var skin = collada.skins[ 0 ];

    dae.scale.x = dae.scale.y = dae.scale.z = 0.002;
    dae.updateMatrix();
    dae.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ shading: THREE.SmoothShading});
    // or something of this sort....
    scene.add(dae);
};
loader.load(modelPath, callBack);
```

I don't know if it would help, but here is another example from the source: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html